# Apache Wicket process only modified rows on a table UI on server side

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

I have a FORM which displaying list of objects in a table with each row displaying every object. So, when user changes the value and clicks on submit, i need to process only the objects which are modified but not all. Can we check whether that row/object is changed and process only that row ?. If possible, please provide details.

Comment: Give some more details about your implementation so that we can help.

Answer (score 1):

If i would to this i would have a listView with custom Panels for each row. The custom panels would have a boolean indicating that this row has been changed. I would set the boolean in an OnChangeAjaxBehavior attached to every form component of this row.
When submitting i would submit only the values of the Panel with the boolean set to true(modiified).